# how to increase list of completed queries on impala query api

Tags: impala

all

impala daemon web-ui provides the /queries api, which includes a list of completed queries.

the query page displays this at the top:
"This page lists all running queries, plus any completed queries that are archived in memory. The size of that archive is controlled with the --query_log_size command line parameter."

but the completed query list is limited to latest 25.

does anyone know if completed query list limit can be increased?

thnx v much for your time on this, mr